# Apache beam BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE very slow

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery, etl, apache-beam

I am trying to store data to BigQuery tables, the process is running fine and inserting the data to the tables, creating it if required and everything is OK.
The main problem I am facing is the long time it takes to create the tables if I required it to remove the previous data before inserting the new one using **WRITE_TRUNCATE**.

```
write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
```

The time taken is really crazy, and unreasonable!!!
Not just the 150 sleeping seconds, but it reach more than 30 minutes for one table!!! and it is just 10,000 records.

Any facing the same issue? how to overcome it?

Comment: I can say that I am seeing similar times running a similar sized job with `WRITE_TRUNCATE` so this would seem to be normal behavior. If you do find a way to speed it up, I'd be interested to know!